# Safe to assume Normal Distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, sampling, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am reading a textbook called *Bayesian Statistics: the Fun Way*, and chapter 10 touches on integrating the pdf of a normal distribution for a sample of 6 observations with a mean of 20.6 and standard deviation of 1.62 from x=10 to x=18.

I understand how the mean and sd was calculated, but is it safe to assume that this sample of 6 follows a normal distribution and could infer its pdf to be a normal distribution pdf?

Comment: Are you given the data set of the $6$ samples?

Comment: Typically you cannot know the distribution but assume something. But with more observations you could check if the empirical distribution appears approximately normal.